# Using OpenCV and gStreamer no element "videotestsrc"

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

Whenever I try use OpenCV with gStreamer it does not find plugins at runtime. I have compiled OpenCV with gStreamer support and I have used brew to install gStreamer and its plugins. The code compiles but at runtime I get `[ WARN:0@0.025] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1426 open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: no element "videotestsrc"`
Here's the code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
VideoCapture cap("videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000");
if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

Mat frame;
while (true) {
    cap.read(frame);
    imshow("Frame", frame);
    if (waitKey(25) >= 0)
        break;
}

cap.release();
destroyAllWindows();

return 0;
}
```

This is how I compiled OpenCV:

```
cmake -S .. -B . -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../OpenCVContrib/modules
```

I used brew to install gStreamer as follows:

```
brew install gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-libav
```

Running gstreamer from the terminal works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Comment: You can try setting the `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variable to the location of `videotestsrc`. That will tell you if its just not finding the plugin, or if there's an error loading the plugin

Comment: When compiling OpenCV it dumps at the end of the cmake generation phase/before building the summary of what is enabled/disabled. Please take a look there and see if for some reason gstreamer support has not been disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making sure OpenCV is built with GStreamer backend:
Add the following command to the beginning of the `main()`:

```
std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl;
```

Make sure that `GStreamer:    YES` is printed (Under `Video I/O:`).

GStreamer application is also have to be installed, and in the execution path (according to your post, this section is covered).
Make sure there is only one installation of GStreamer in the system.

Note:
Executing your code, I am getting other error (warning) message: `GStreamer warning: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline` (but I am using Windows 10).

---

The default OpenCV backend is FFmpeg, for using GStreamer we have to explicitly add `CAP_GSTREAMER` argument.
Note: It looks like GStreamer is opened automatically, so it's probably not the issue.

---

The GStreamer pipeline defined in your post applies video encoding pipeline.
The pipeline may work with `VideoWriter`, but not with `VideoCapture`.

In general, VideoCapture sink supposed to be "decoded" raw video in BGR format (I am not sure which other formats are supported by OpenCV).
We may use the following pipeline:

```
VideoCapture cap("videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=BGR ! appsink", CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

---

Code sample:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main() {
    std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl;

    //VideoCapture cap("videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000", CAP_GSTREAMER);
    VideoCapture cap("videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=BGR ! appsink", CAP_GSTREAMER);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat frame;
    while (true) {
        cap.read(frame);
        imshow("Frame", frame);
        if (waitKey(1) >= 0)
            break;
    }

    cap.release();
    destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Sample output (width=160,height=120):
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive explanation. It increased my understanding and got me up 'n running. Adding appsink into the pipeline was critical. As suggested, format also needed changing. I also had to update GST_PLUGIN_PATH as suggested by @dast99.